# Decoding base64 input with a Buffer object

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, decoding

I have a client interface that sends binary data encoded in base64. The data is a 29 byte custom formatted payload of bytes that describes an event. The 29 bytes is made up of a number of fields; each with unique lengths.

I need the server to decode that so I can extract the fields. I've tried using the [Buffer](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/buffers.html) object as I did with another use case where the [data was passed in hex format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058424/node-js-data-parsing-raw-bytes-with-buffer), without success.

```
buff = new Buffer('AR0AAAEKCgsLDAwAAATSAAAADsgAAAAAAAAAzMQ=', 'base64');

// track the current position
// ... get out to the data portion of the message
var position = 3;

// event type
var event_type = buff.slice(position,(position+3)).toString('utf8');
position += 3;
console.log('... event type: ' + event_type + ' /');

// address
var addr = buff.slice(position,(position+3)).toString('utf8');
position += 3;
console.log('... addr: ' + addr + ' /');
```

The .toString('utf8') is likely the root cause. How can I get to a String that represents the desired bytes in these slice() calls?

I'm not storying binary data on the server as one might normally do with base64 encoding. So should I be going from base64 to some other encoding to access the individual bytes?

I've used the same code on a known text string that is encoded with base64 to verify the basic logic. But when the source data is binary before being encoded, the console statements don't print anything. Can I go from binary to base64 to strings?

Comment: What doesn't work? Also, is the data in the fields really utf8?

Comment: Nothing is printed in those console statements... I just updated the question to reflect the fact that I've verified the code path with a known text string that is encoded with base64.

Comment: Do it print `... event type:  /` or nothing?

Comment: Works for me (although there are weird bytes in your data, it's just whitespace and a onebyte)

Comment: One thing I've discovered along the way is that the parameters used in slice() are indexes - as opposed to byte offsets. So my current approach simply won't work. I need to learn how to transform the base64 data into a byte stream or array of hex values and chope those up to get down to the individual bytes within the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this implementation is the use of slice() to dissect the byte stream. The parameters to slice() are indexes - not byte offsets. This seems like a pretty big flaw. I'm not sure why anyone would do that when interacting with a buffer.

Regardless, the solution is to access the buff as an array.

```
// event type
var event_type = buff[position].toString('utf8');
position += 1;
console.log('... event type: ' + event_type + ' /');

// address
var addr = buff[position].toString('utf8');
position += 1;
console.log('... addr: ' + addr + ' /');
```

If you want to concatenate multiple bytes (the original example has 3 byte lengths), you have to loop over the array indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The data does not seem to have valid ASCII or UTF-8 strings, the event_type and addr is some binary data. Use hexadecimal presentation and print that.

```
var event_type = buff.slice(3,6).toString('hex');  => '00010a'
```